# Python/Discord When I try to make python get the userID of a discord user it just does nothing, no error message and no output

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This is the code using the userID:

```
if message.content == "MMO start":
    dir = r'C:\\Users\\User\Desktop\MMOProfiles'
    MessageAuthor = str(userID)
    newpath = os.path.join(dir,MessageAuthor)
    doesExist = os.path.exists(newpath)
    if doesExist == False:
        await message.channel.send("Creating profile")
        os.makedirs(newpath)
    if doesExist == True:
        await message.channel.send("You already have a profile")
```

And this is the function which is defining the userID:

```
async def UserID(ctx):
    userID = ctx.author.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The userID is already inside the `userID` you can type `print(userID)` to see it in terminal.

Comment: How do I make it make a file with UserID's though?

Comment: You can use file handling in python. For me, I use JSON files but it can also be txt